# Columns must be same length as ke by using lru_cache

Tags: python, pandas, caching, functools

I have a problem. I want to get the coordinates `long` and `lat` from the address. I want to check directly in the method whether this address already has a `long` and `lat` value and if so, should this be taken and not queried again via `geolocator.geocode(df['address'])`.  Unfortunately I got an error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`.

Dataframe

```py
                                         address  customer
0              Surlej, 7513, Silvaplana, Schweiz         1
1  Vodnikova cesta 35, 1000 Ljubljana, Slowenien         2
2              Surlej, 7513, Silvaplana, Schweiz         1
```

Code

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='testing_stackoverflow')

import pandas as pd
d = {
    "address": ['Surlej, 7513, Silvaplana, Schweiz', 'Vodnikova cesta 35, 1000 Ljubljana, Slowenien', 'Surlej, 7513, Silvaplana, Schweiz',],
    "customer": [1, 2, 1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def function_that_returns_lat_lon_from_address(address):
    location = geolocator.geocode(address, timeout=10)
    print(location)
    try:
        if (location == None):
            return(None, None)
        else:
            return (location.latitude, location.longitude)
    except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
        print("Timeout ", e)
        return(None, None)

df[['lat', 'lon']] = df['address'].apply(function_that_returns_lat_lon_from_address)
```

What I want

```py
                                         address  customer   latitude  \
0              Surlej, 7513, Silvaplana, Schweiz         1  46.459902   
1  Vodnikova cesta 35, 1000 Ljubljana, Slowenien         2  46.065523   
2              Surlej, 7513, Silvaplana, Schweiz         1  46.459902   

   longitude  
0   9.803370  
1  14.490775  
2   9.803370
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4873cdd27090> in <module>()
     24         return(None, None)
     25 
---> 26 df[['lat', 'lon']] = df['address'].apply(function_that_returns_lat_lon_from_address)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _iset_not_inplace(self, key, value)
   3673         if self.columns.is_unique:
   3674             if np.shape(value)[-1] != len(key):
-> 3675                 raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
   3676 
   3677             for i, col in enumerate(key):

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: can you include the full trace please

Comment: @Yuca sure. Please see my edit, thanks.

Comment: also the GeocoderTimedOut is not declared in your example

Comment: what happens if you store the result into a generic object, like `test` instead of `df[[...]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution to the problem

Convert series into list of tuples so that you have two items on each row to assign back to two columns. In this case pandas will automatically take care of unpacking tuples and assigning the unpacked values back to two columns

A slightly faster solution

```
df[['lat', 'lon']] = list(map(function_that_returns_lat_lon_from_address, df.address))
```

Or you can also fix your code by simply adding `.tolist` conversion,

```
df[['lat', 'lon']] = df['address'].apply(function_that_returns_lat_lon_from_address).tolist()
```